# How to compute the size of line or strings which consists of many words in c?

Tags: c, string, string-length

> I have written this code to differentiate between spaces and newline characters so that I can compute the length of the whole text from user input. I actually need to compute the length of the text so that I can allocate space for that length in a linked list.

```
char s[24];
int l=0,i;
scanf("%s",s);
for(i=0;;){
    if(s[i]==' ') {
     l++;
     i++;
    }
    else if (s[i]=='\0') break;
    else {
    l++;
    i++;
    }
}

printf("%d",l);
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? And do you realise your if and else do the same thing?

Comment: And your loop is infinite because you commented out the test for `s[i]=='\0'`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to count?  The number of non-blank characters in the entire string, or the number of characters in each word?  Also, I see no check for newlines but you mention them in the question.  Please state exactly what you're trying to count.

Comment: the above commented line is by mistake...

Comment: now i have edited it... I just wanna know as in c whitespace characters are actually '\0' so how can we differentiate b/w space and newline...

Comment: I am trying to count the number of characters including spaces.

Comment: What is the variable l? It increases in both first "if" block and last "else" block.

Comment: I hve take l for length yaa if it's space then also my l should increment and if its any character then also my l should increment.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in a very shout piece of code with some functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[24];
    fgets(s,24,stdin);
    if( s[strlen(s)-1] == '\n'){
        s[strlen(s)-1] = '\0';
    }
    printf("%lu\n",strlen(s));
    return 0;
}
```

You should not use scanf. Because meet with space, it stops. And it is unsafe to use scanf(). fgets() is a better choice.

Tested with GCC and Linux.

Update: Thanks to @wildplasser, there was a bug in my code. After fixing the bug, new code without string.h is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t my_strlen(char * str){
    size_t length = 0;
    while( str[length++] != '\0' ){;}
    return length-1;
}

int main(void)
{
    char s[24];
    size_t len=0;
    if( fgets(s,24,stdin) == NULL ){
        printf("Error in reading string.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    len = my_strlen(s);
    if( len > 0 && s[len-1] == '\n'){
        --len;
    }
    printf("%zd\n",len);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how can we do it without using string.h

Comment: `s[strlen(s)-1] = 0;` is unsafe. strlen() could return 0. (fgets can yield a string starting with '\0' ) Also: calling strlen() twice is not needed.

Comment: @bak2trak We could write a function to get the length by ourselves. See my update.

Comment: @wildplasser Thanks very much for your comments! I improved my code. Thank you!

Comment: That's much better. Next step would be to use a size_t, not an int for len.

Comment: @wildplasser I really appreciate your suggestions! I modify it again. Is there any more issue? Thank you for your time and instructions.

Comment: `size_t my_strlen(char * str){ size_t length; for (length=0 ;str[length]; length++ ) {;}  
    return length;`
} AND `len = my_strlen(s);
    while ( len > 0 && s[len-1] == '\n'){ s[--len] = 0; }`

Comment: @wildplasser The first suggestion is quite good! But in terms of the second one, I do not think it is necessary. According to the definition of function fgets():"Reads characters from stream and stores them as a C string into str until (num-1) characters have been read or either a newline or the end-of-file is reached, whichever happens first." So there is at most one newline character.

Comment: No. The EOF can be hit **before** an '\n' is encountered. No need to discuss. I already said everything.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27515/discussion-between-sheng-and-wildplasser)

Comment: your updated `while( str[length++] != '\0' ){;}` can never return zero. The for loop was there for a reason! Please reread my comment...

Comment: sheng and @wildplasser thanks for your help one last thing..which I don't understand is what is the use of this statement....
if( len > 0 && s[len-1] == '\n'){
        --len;

Comment: You misread it. It was: `len = my_strlen(s); while ( len > 0 && s[len-1] == '\n'){ s[--len] = 0; }` nine hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

Per the question in your title, `<string.h>` has a strlen() function that will count the number of characters up to the null terminator in a string. It looks like you may be doing something different in your code, though.

Comment: I am trying to count the number of characters including spaces.forget strlen thats by mistake..